# How to pass user activation to iframe to open file chooser dialog

Tags: iframe

Trying to open an upload file dialog(through file input element) embedded in an iframe upon click of a button in the parent window. Instead, this error is thrown "File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation.". Parent window and iframe source are hosted in different domains.

Is there any way to transfer user activation to iframe?

Comment: Also looking for the same thing, but for the ability to play audio when the parent frame is activated. Seems like we need something akin to the sandbox attribute `allow-downloads-without-user-activation`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#sandbox - we want something like `share-user-activation`. I've added an issue about this here: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/9237